# Error calling a stored procedure PHP and Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I have the following issue. I have a stored procedure in Oracle. When I call the procedure in PHP, it gave me  the following error:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ning�n dato ORA-06512: en "ESTUDIANTE.P_CONSULTA_LIBRO", l�nea 9 ORA-06512: en l�nea 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\biblioteca\prueba.php on line 11
```

The procedure in Oracle is working properly, but I don't know what it's happening. I'm new to coding in PHP.

This is the code in PHP

```html
<?php

require_once 'conexion.php';


$sql = 'BEGIN p_consulta_libro(:variable); END;';
$stmt_id = oci_parse($conexion, $sql);
$variable=0111;
oci_bind_by_name($stmt_id, 'variable', $variable);

$res = oci_execute($stmt_id);

print_r($res, true);

?>
```

This is the stored procedure in oracle

```html
create or replace procedure p_consulta_libro(idlibro in number )
as

obra varchar2(200);
autor varchar2(50);
valores varchar2(200);

BEGIN
select  L.TITULO, A.NOMBRE_AUTOR into obra, autor 
from LIBRO L, AUTOR A
where L.ID_LIBRO = idlibro  AND A.ID_AUTOR = L.ID_AUTOR ;
valores:=concat(concat(obra,' '),autor);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El libro es... '||valores);
end;
```

I call the procedure using this sentence in Oracle

```html
set serveroutput on
BEGIN 
p_consulta_libro(0111);
END;
```

Comment: "Store procedure"? What's that?

Comment: ORA-01403 is "no data found"  the select statement is not returning any value, but a "select into..." requires a value to be returned.

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine on Oracle. I do have a value on the database.

Comment: No, you don't, that's the error you get. Apart from that, your procedure does not make any sense. You select a value but you don't return anything. The DBMS_OUTPUT is not visible in php as far as I know.

Comment: If you mean it's working fine in a tool like SQL*Plus that fetches DBMS_OUTPUT automatically, then you can do the equivalent and fetch DBMS_OUTPUT manually in PHP, see page 210 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf).  However it would be more efficient and better to return values directly from PL/SQL without calling DBMS_OUTPUT.  See other examples in the book.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP, but - from Oracle-ish point of view, perhaps you'd rather use a **function** that returns value; if there's nothing to be found, handle that **exception** and return something else (a message, or even an empty string).

Also, a hint or two:

- you don't have to first select values into locally declared variables and then concatenate them
- nowadays, it is suggested that we *separate* joins from conditions (which should be put into the `where` clause), so - don't comma-separate tables in the `from` clause and join them in `where` - *properly* `join` them
- concatenation - in Oracle - is way simpler if you use the double pipe `||` concatenation operator, instead of nested `concat` function calls

Something like this:

```
create or replace function f_consulta_libro (p_idlibro in number)
  return varchar2
as
  l_valores varchar2(200);
begin
  select l.titulo ||' '|| a.nombre_autor
    into l_valores
    from libro l join autor a on a.id_autor = l.id_autor
    where l.id_libro = p_idlibro;

  return l_valores;
  
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return 'Nothing has been found';
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The number `0111` gets treated as [octal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) so it is not the number 111.

In your particular example you don't need PL/SQL.  Just execute the SQL query directly:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$c = oci_connect("hr", "welcome", "localhost/XEPDB1");
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

// Use a NOWDOC for SQL, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier
// Note there is no trailing semi-colon after the SQL
$sql =<<<PHPEND
  select  L.TITULO || ' ' || A.NOMBRE_AUTOR
  from LIBRO L, AUTOR A
  where L.ID_LIBRO = :idlibro  AND A.ID_AUTOR = L.ID_AUTOR
PHPEND;

$s = oci_parse($c, "select * from employees where salary > :sbv");
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$id = 111;   // Note no leading 0
$r = oci_bind_by_name($s, ':idlibro', $id);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not bind a parameter: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
$ncols = oci_num_fields($s);
echo "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
    $colname = oci_field_name($s, $i);
    echo "  <th><b>".htmlspecialchars($colname,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE)."</b></th>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $item!==null?htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE):"&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```